# How to create models in cakephp using the command prompt

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp to develop my project and I want to create models using the command prompt as that is easier than creating models manually. As I'm using the windows environment. 
I edited the path in my computer/advanced settings/environment variable/system variable as below.

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\wamp\www\fit or fat\lib\Cake\Console;

(I have renamed my cakephp folder as fit or fat)
But whwn I enter the 'cake bake ' command in cmd I'm getting the error message that cake is not recognized as an internal or external command. 
Is there anything else I have to do/

Comment: You don't need to modify your path (infact, I'd say it's a bad idea to do so) to use the cli, just `cd path\to\app` and (any os) `Console\cake`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you need to use `cake.bat` instead just `cake` which is for *nix.

Also you can run `bake` without environment variables setting just do the following

```
cd "C:\wamp\www\fit or fat"
lib\Cake\Console\cake.bat bake
```

but you need to setup correct correct path to your php anyway.

If you want to just run bake without any setting do the following

```
cd "C:\wamp\www\fit or fat"
c:\wamp\php\bin\php.exe lib\Cake\Console\cake.php bake
```

please check path to your php executable, it can differ from mine `c:\wamp\php\bin\php.exe`

Comment: there's a [cake executable in the application](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/app/Console) - it's not necessary to refer to the one in lib.

Comment: thank you very much. this answer is very useful for me. I use this method like c:\wamp\php\bin\php.exe C:\wamp\www\cakephp-3-1-0\bin\cake.php bake.